# Passing an array variable from JS to PHP using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays

I have a array variable in jQuery which is created as follows:

```
var values = $('input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
    }).get();
```

Assume the values in the array variable as 1,2,3. I am trying to pass this variable to php using the below ajax call:

```
doAjaxCallDelete("delete_checked", "values");
```

The ajax function is written as below:

```
function doAjaxCallDelete(mode, values) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        type: "post",
        data: {mode: mode, values: values},
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            responseData = data;
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Connection error. Please contact administrator. Thanks.');
        }
    }); 
    return responseData;
}
```

I am retrieving this value in php using:

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST["values"];
```

But when I echo `$myArray` its showing 'values' instead of the real values inside the variable.
Can anybody suggest a solution to pass values of the array variable properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the double quotes you use in the function call

```
doAjaxCallDelete("delete_checked", "values");
```

you pass a string "values" instead of variable values.

use `doAjaxCallDelete("delete_checked", values);` instead.

> note:
>
> use $_POST['values'];

Comment: What a silly mistake from my part. Thank you so much for pointing that out......was giving me a headache. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: it happens, all the best ;)